Why is this only getting the first 25 movie titles?
I was practicing web scrapers and trying to pull the top 250 movies from IMDB. For some reason it only grabs the first 25 titles though. Anyone know why?
url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250"
response = response = requests.get(url, headers={
    "user-agent": "*THIS WAS A USER AGENT BUT I'M HIDING IT BECAUSE IDK IF A SHOULD PUT THAT INFO IN HERE*"
                  "Safari/537.36"})
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('a', class_="ipc-title-link-wrapper")
print(titles)

for title in titles:
    title = title.find('h3', class_='ipc-title__text').get_text()
    print(title)


There's nothing secret about user agents.

I'm going to guess it's because you used requests, which does not process javascript.

Use View Source to see what the HTML code is. There are only 25 class="ipc-title-link-wrapper" in the HTML. The rest must be added dynamically with JS.
